# Trying to add my php config to PHP-FPM in Docker

Tags: php, docker

so I'm using a Docker container based on "php:7.4-fpm" and trying to move my project to PHP-FPM from mod_php, and looking in the built docker image I see that there is no /etc/php.ini file, so I google a bit and the ini file used by php-fpm is in /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf, which in turn contains the following line in the end:

```
include=etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf
```

Great, so I added a "runtime.conf" file to that directory with this content:

```
include_path = ".:/usr/share/php:/Atlas/Core/include/:/Atlas/Core/include/classes/"
error_reporting  = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING
```

Using the COPY method in the Dockerfile, cool. So I build it, but when I then run it, I get this:

```
[15-Jun-2020 15:47:56] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/runtime.conf:1] unknown entry 'include_path'
[15-Jun-2020 15:47:56] ERROR: Unable to include /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/runtime.conf from /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf at line 1
```

Indicating that I can't use "include_path" for PHP-FPM, I have been googling on this but I have found nothing that tells me why this is? How do I set the include_path for PHP-FPM? Is there something wonky about this Docker image?

Comment: Check that it actually COPY the file...And check if you're doing something with VOLUME this happens in NPM for example. So, check that VOLUME is actually there to copy the file to both sides in case you change it and that should helps in case the Docker removes from some reason the files.

Comment: @Asfo Yes, the copy is working, since the error message specifically singles out the file. And if I remove the COPY the docker runs fine (albeit without the correct include_path)

Comment: But then, check the VOLUME. This could be the case, if you have the VOLUME pointing to the same path, then, that could be the error because VOLUME is "re-copying" the file, but your PHP tried to start when that is happening in your "CMD" 

Comment: @Asfo I know what you mean, but I accidentally named the file runtime.ini first and it was copied and not read by PHP, making the image run so I could login to it and see the file. The file is properly copied, and PHP is complaining about the content of it, i.e. the "include_path" which is found in it. So the problem is that for some reason I can't set include_path in PHP-FPM using *.conf files in /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d

Comment: PHP config and PHP-FPM config are two separate things. You're putting PHP config in the FPM directory, FPM can't read it, and is giving you an error telling you that.

Comment: @Sammitch Great! So where do I put "include_path" so it will be used by PHP-FPM?

Comment: In the actual php.ini, or a path wildcard included therefrom.